# Расширения C#, как реализовать модификацию структуры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть struct `Vector3`,и когда ты хочешь менять только одну его переменную, ты пишешь что то вроде

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, 5);
```

Чтобы не делать каждый раз одно и то же, решил написать расширение

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
public static Vector3 ChangeZ(this Vector3 original, float z)
{
    return new Vector3(original.x, original.y, z);
}
}
```

И теперь я пишу

```
 transform.position.ChangeZ(5);
```

И оно не работает! Значение `transform.position` таким методом не меняется, а традиционным - вполне. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `transform.position = transform.position.ChangeZ(5);` ?

Comment: Счёл нужным отредактировать заголовок, т. к. суть вопроса именно в различии между значимыми и ссылочными типами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в логике. Посмотрите на Ваше расширение - оно не меняет экземпляр Трансформ, в котором Вы вызываете метод `ChangeZ`. Ваш метод ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ необходимое Вам значение.

Поэтому в текущей реализации Вам нужно делать таким образом:

```
transform.position = transform.position.ChangeZ(5);
```

Либо изменить расширение на следующий вариант (только модифицировать не Vector3, а Transform):

```
public static void ChangeZ(this Transform original, float z)
{
    original.position = new Vector3(original.position.x, original.position.y, z);
}
```

Comment: `Либо изменить расширение на следующий вариант:` вы уверены, что это будет работать?

Comment: @tym32167, будет если заменить на `ref this` :)

Comment: @tym32167, Ваша правда, спасибо! Действительно, работать не будет - поторопился. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, заработало бы, если бы использовал `ref this` в определении расширения